# Pushing my app to cloudControl (PaaS) fails: hook declined

Tags: deployment, push, paas, cloudcontrol

When trying to push and deploy my app to cloudControlled PaaS:

```
$ cctrlapp MY_APP/default push
```

I get the following error (reduced output):

```
remote: -----> Receiving push
remote: /srv/www/buildpacks/php/bin/compile: line 81: /srv/tmp/builddir/code/composer.phar: Permission denied
remote:  !     cloudControl push rejected, failed to compile php app
remote:  !
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
To ssh://MY_APP@cloudcontrolled.com/repository.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://MY_APP@cloudcontrolled.com/repository.git'
Command '['PATH_TO_GIT', 'push', u'ssh://MY_APP@cloudcontrolled.com/repository.git', 'master']'
returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I have to remove the `composer.phar` file from the root directory of my repository. Too keep it in my local filesystem, I did

```
git rm --cached composer.phar
# then commit, push, deploy
```

Comment: If you want to provide a custom composer.phar this is supported (e.g. for when you need a specific version). It seems the error was caused by the composer.phar you had in your repository root not having correct permissions. It seems your on Windows, I'm not sure how you that has/could have affected this. I openen a ticket in the buildpack and we'll have a look if there is anything we can do.

Comment: Here's the ticket for completeness. https://github.com/cloudControl/buildpack-php/issues/11